# post value of checkbox is empty

Tags: php, forms

I am trying to get checked values in unos.php file. I get empty post but could not figure it out where is mistake.

I want to check just one checkbox and according to post value received I will perform results.

```
<form method="post" action="unos.php">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="izmjena">Izmjena</button>
    <table>  
    <thead>
    <tr>
    <th data-field="artikal" data-checkbox="true"  > </th>
    <th data-field="id" data-sortable="true">Id</th>
    <th data-field="sifra" data-sortable="true">Sifra</th>
    <th data-field="name" data-sortable="true">Naziv</th>
    <th data-field="mjera" data-sortable="true">Jed. mjere</th>
    <th data-field="stanjesa" data-sortable="true">Stanje Sa</th>
    <th data-field="stanjebl" data-sortable="true">Stanje BL</th>
    <th data-field="minkolicina" data-sortable="true">Min kolicina</th>
    <th data-field="kategorija" data-sortable="true">Kategorija</th>
    <th data-field="status" data-sortable="true">Status</th>
    <th data-field="print" data-sortable="true">P</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody> 
    <?php while ($r = $q->fetch()): ?>
    <tr>   
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="artikli" value="<?.$r['ArtId'].?>"></td>
    <td><?=$r['ArtId'] ?></td>
    <td><?=$r['ArtSifra'] ?></td>
    <td><?=$r['ArtNaziv'] ?></td>
    <td><?=$r['JmNaziv'] ?></td>
    <td><?=$r['ArtStanje']?></td>
    <td><?=$r['ArtStanjeMo'] ?></td>
    <td><?=$r['ArtMinKolic'] ?></td>
    <td><?=$r['KatNaziv'] ?></td>
    <td><?=$r['ArtAktivan'] ?></td> 
    <td><a onClick="window.open('kartica-artikla.php?id= <?=$r['ArtKategorija']?>','Websoft','width=800,height=500,left=0,top=100,screenX=0,screenY=100,menubar=yes,scrollbars=yes')" href ""> 
    <img src="../../img/kartica.png" width="20"></td>
    </tr>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
    </tfoot>
    </table>
```

file unos.php.. In this file I want to post value of checkbox

```
    <?php 
    if (isset($_POST["izmjena"])) {

    $id=$_POST["artikli"];
    echo $id;                      
    var_dump($id);
     } 
     else{ 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
<td><input type="checkbox" name="artikli" value="<?.$r['ArtId'].?>"></td>
```

To:

```
<td><input type="checkbox" name="artikli" value="<?php echo $r['ArtId']; ?>"></td>
```

Dont forget to close your form either :)

Answer (score 0):

`checkbox`'s value will be present if it is checked. Do this -

```
$id=(!empty($_POST["artikli"])) ? $_POST["artikli"] : false;
```

and you are not echoing the whole html so no need to concate. Change -

```
<td><input type="checkbox" name="artikli" value="<? echo $r['ArtId'];?>"></td>
```

Comment: when I do var_dump($id) i get --string(0) "" it does not display result

Comment: try var_dump($_POST["artikli"]) and see what you are getting?

Comment: That means it is not checked. SO instead of `''` assign `false` and add the checks accordingly.

Comment: It should be false now as it is not posted.

Comment: Yes but I check one checkbox and hit submit still displays bool(false)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using several checkboxes, you should be using an input checkbox with the following "name": "artikli[]".

The "[]" will send an array of values instead of sending a string.

Code:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="artikli[]" value="<?.$r['ArtId'].?>" />
```